# Help with two complex sets / manifolds (Algebraic surfaces? )

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, manifolds, complex-geometry

I've been working on symplectic geometry, and I've encountered this two complex sets (manifolds) in $\mathbb{C}^4$:

$A_1 =\{ (z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4) \enspace | \enspace |z_1|^2+|z_3|^2=a , \enspace |z_2|^2 + |z_4|^2 = b   \}$

$A_2 =\{ (z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4) \enspace | \enspace |z_1|^2+|z_3|^2=a , \enspace |z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 + |z_4|^2 = b   \}$

In both cases I need to find the manifold:

$$ M_i= A_i / T^2$$

where $T^2$ is the torus. I've read that these manifolds $M_i$ are "Hirzebruch" surfaces. No idea about it though. As I have never taken a course of complex surfaces or algebraic surfaces, sm question is what manifolds are $A_1$ and $A_2$? In order to compute the quotient. Or how can I show $M_i$ are Hirzebruch surfaces?

By the way the torus action considered is the standard hamiltonian action :

$$ (e^{i\theta_1},e^{i\theta_2},e^{i\theta_3},e^{i\theta_4}) \cdot  (z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)= (e^{i\theta_1} z_1,e^{i\theta_2} z_2,e^{i\theta_3} z_3,e^{i\theta_4} z_4).$$

Comment: Could you please say (i.e., add to your question) how the torus acts on $\mathbf{C}^{4}$? (As a partial answer, $A_{1}$ is a product of three-spheres of radius $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$, and presumably quotienting out the torus action gives a product of $2$-spheres.)

Comment: Thanks, it was my guess about $A_1$. Added the action too in post.

Comment: Thank you for the additional details. :) I'm still confused about the action, however, since your group appears to be a real $4$-torus: Doesn't $T^{2}$ refer to a real $2$-torus (as the dimension count suggests)? If so, does that mean there's a diagonal embedding somewhere?

Comment: Hm.. Maybe I've confused the action you meant. The quotient of $A_2$ by $T^2$ I think is given by the subset $N \{(e^{i\theta}+e^{i\varphi},e^{i\varphi},e^{i\theta},e^{i\varphi})\enspace | \enspace \theta,\varphi \in [0,2\pi] \} \cong T^2$. It is a restriction of the standard hamiltonian $T^4$ action. Then I have $M_2=A_2/T^2$.

Comment: Ah, yes, that (a two-parameter family of automorphisms) is the type of thing I meant. :)